# Magnetic charge and magnetic fine structure constant in SI units

Tags: electromagnetism, si-units

What are the definitions and values of the elementary magnetic charge and the magnetic fine structure constant in SI units?

What are the relations with the elementary electric charge and the electric fine structure constant?

I found it difficult to get this right, so I hope the answer is usefull for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Physics/Essays/Fedosin/Magnetic_coupling_constant) and [this](https://www.ph-ludwigsburg.de/fileadmin/subsites/2f-phys-t-01/Starauschek/magnetische_monopole_sk_1998.pdf) source, we have:

$$
 eg=h   \\
\alpha \beta = \frac{1}{4}
$$

where $e=1.6\cdot10^{-19}$ C the elementary electric charge and $g=4.1\cdot10^{-15}$ Wb the elementary magnetic charge and $h=6.63\cdot10^{-34}$ Js the constant of Planck and $\alpha$ the electric fine structure constant and $\beta$ the magnetic fine structure constant.

The dimensionless values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are
$$
\alpha = \frac{1}{137.036} \\[8mm] 
\beta = 34.26
$$

The definitions are:
$$
\alpha = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{e^2}{\hbar c} = \frac{e^2}{ 2\epsilon_0 h c} = \frac{\mu_0 h c}{ 2 g^2} \\
\beta = \frac{1}{4\pi \mu_0} \frac{g^2}{\hbar c} = \frac{g^2}{ 2\mu_0 h c} =
\frac{\epsilon_0 h c}{ 2 e^2}
$$

And analogously to the law of Coulomb
$$
F_e = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{q_{e,1}q_{e,2}}{r^2}
$$
you have
$$
F_m = \frac{1}{4\pi \mu_0} \frac{q_{m,1}q_{m,2}}{r^2}.
$$

Comment: If the idea was to write something that was useful and immediately understandable, then the convoluted structure and lack of explanations put this rather wide off the mark.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Whether this is useful depends on background and how you judge. I e.g. never got the various methods of em-units in my system.

Comment: If what you've written works for you, then great. If the idea was to write something that was useful for others, then one way to see whether that's the case is to listen to the feedback. (Or not, if you don't want to. There's plenty of bad textbooks out there whose authors lead perfectly happy lives ignoring the feedback.) This Q&A is a good idea but the answer is structured backwards to what it ought to, and it does not read as a self-contained post, which it should.

Comment: I'm happy to provide further reasonings, alternatives, or other constructive feedback, *if* you want it. Or you can just sulk, too, but then I'm not sure on what grounds you might complain about downvotes.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I wrote this decent Q&A primarily for myself although your students may benefit as well some day. I am content as it is and I believe that the nice formule $eg=h$ is terribly underrated.

Comment: For some (until now unknown) reasons some users of the site want to close the question. That's the way this site works - all in the game - but personally I find it rather silly, because both Q and A are perfectly ordinary.

Comment: Note that the close votes are not mine. I sincerely doubt that this resource will be useful to anyone else - it is structured backwards and it's just too much trouble to make sense of; students are better served going elsewhere - but if you want to let pass an opportunity to listen to your readers then that's your business.

Comment: I see it differently in this case. Doesn't mean I don't appreciate your efforts.